# Использование не всех аргументов в функции Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, функции, type-error

Есть в наличии код:

```
class Fractional:
    #create fractional
    def __init__(self, integer, numerator, denominator):
        if integer == None:
            self.integer = 0
        else:
            self.integer = integer

        if numerator == None:
            self.numerator = 0
        elif numerator < 0 and integer != 0:
            raise TypeError('Numerator must be more than 0') 
        else:
            self.numerator = numerator

        if denominator == None and numerator != None:
            raise TypeError('You must enter denominator')
        elif denominator == None and numerator == None:
            return integer
        elif denominator <= 0:
            raise TypeError('Denominator must be more than 0')
        else:
            self.denominator = denominator
```

Изначально я думал, что аргументы, которые в функцию не передали, получают значение None и, соответственно, сделал такие вот if/elif/else. Но в итоге, если я передаю только один аргумент (который уходит в integer) (например: `Fractional(2)` ), то код ругается вот такими вот словами:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'numerator' and 'denominator'
> ```

Из чего я понимаю, что просто так с None не отделаться. Пробовал так же писать `is`, но, видимо, это из другой степи и тоже мне не помогло. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему, чтобы можно было вводить в функцию только один аргумент и опускать остальные два.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо задать аргументы по умолчанию в определении функции. Сделать это можно так:

```
class Fractional:
    #create fractional
    def __init__(self, integer, numerator=None, denominator=None):
    ...
```

Дополнительно, у вас есть еще одна ошибка.
Код `return integer` приведет к ошибке, т.к. метод `__init__` не должен возвращать ничего кроме `None`

Comment: Воспользовался вашим советом и получил вот такие вот строки:

>>> x = Fractional(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'

Comment: Возможно вам не нужен класс, а будет достаточно просто процедуры, если вы хотите возвращать результат

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете указать значения по умолчанию:

```py
def __init__(self, integer, numerator=None, denominator=None):
    ....
```